# Android layoutparms scrollvew height

Tags: android, tableview, scrollview

I have a tableview inside of a scrollview.  I want to reserve space for a listview 2/3 of the screen. I am getting the height of the screen, and will divide that in 2/3 and set the height of the ScrollView.  But even with manually x and y numbers its blowing up.

App is crashing when I set the ScrollView width and height like this:

```
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.usdScroll);

    ScrollView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ScrollView.LayoutParams( -1, 550);
    sv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the layout_weight attribute to specify how much of a view the specific component will use, e.g. `android:layout_weight=2`. So for your listView set a weight of 1 and a weight of 2 for your tableview, I think. Anyway, play with the weight setting and you can split the view in any ratio you like.

Answer (score 1):

LayoutParams is used to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. So the layout param's type which you set to must match its parent class type exactly.

and here is a better solution, using layout_weight instead. Try this please

```
<ScrollView android:layout_weight="1" ........></ScrollView>
<ListView  android:layout_weight="2" ........></ListView>
```